# Index Match if begins with

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to do an index match based on two criteria. I've tried:

`=index(B1:B4, match("*do", if(a1:a4 = "*Blue", b1:b4)),2)`

```
     A           B       C
_____________________________
1| Blue       | 5   | dotson
2| Yellow     | 3   | dodo
3| Yellow     | 8   | cat
4| Blue-Green | 7   | dog
```

I want the formula to return:

```
5
7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This formula will do it. Enter it into any empty cell in row 2:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$C$4,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("blue",$A$1:$A$4))*ISNUMBER(SEARCH("do",$C$1:$C$4)),ROW($C$1:$C$4)),ROW(1:1)),2),"")
```

> This is an array formula and must be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Now copy and select a range one cell down and as deep as you need and paste.

Note: change the 4s in the formula to a row number that will meet your needs in terms of depth.

Note: this is a culling formula. The value 5 will appear in row 2 and the value 7 will appear in row 3, etc.

Comment: It is very close @ExcelHero! My only problem is if the column that is returning (Col B above) has a cell that is empty when the parameters are matched it returns a 0 instead of nothing.

Comment: @SHarris That is simply how Excel works... always. For example, say cell A1 is completely blank. Now in another cell enter the formula `=A1` and you'll see that the result of the formula is not blank, but ZERO. The exact same thing happens here when the INDEX function returns the correct cell. Really the only way to override this admittedly odd behavior is to wrap a formula in an explicit test for the blank, like so: `=IF(yourformula="","",yourformula)` and you can do that to my formula above, and it will obviously be twice as long... but it will handle the blanks the way you want.

Comment: that's exactly what I did! Thanks for you help!

Comment: if I wanted to do a slight variation and match the exact phrase "Blue" can I replace Search("Blue", $A$1:$A$4) with MATCH("Blue",  $A$1:$A$4, 0)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91666/discussion-between-s-harris-and-excel-hero).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this without getting `INDEX` or `MATCH` involved via:

```
=IF(AND(LEFT(A1:A4, 4) = "Blue", LEFT(C1:C4, 2) = "do"), B1:B4)
```